# Using JSON for configuration file. How to include comments on rewrite?

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to use JSON for saving and reading configuration files. I would like to have the option of using comments inside the configuration file. A comment line should start with the hash sign `#` as for regular Perl comments.

It is no problem reading the configuration file, but when I want to write back on disk all the comments are lost. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;
use JSON::XS;

my $json  = JSON::XS->new->relaxed->pretty->canonical;
my $str = '
{
  # Here we assign a value of 1 to a
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : {
     "c" : 3,  # and c should be equal to 3
     "d" : 4
  }
}
  ';
my $h = $json->decode($str);
#say $str;
#dd $h;
$h->{b}{a} = 2;
my $new_str = $json->encode($h);
say $new_str;
```

The output is:

```
{
   "a" : "1",
   "b" : {
      "a" : 2,
      "c" : "3",
      "d" : "4"
   }
}
```

whereas the expected output would be:

```
{
  # Here we assign a value of 1 to a
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : {
     "a" : 2,
     "c" : 3,  # and c should be equal to 3
     "d" : 4
  }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve with JSON, or is there other configuration file formats that are better suited for this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), "JSON does not provide or allow any sort of comment syntax."

Perhaps you could allow comment nodes in the data. Something like:

```
{
  "comment" : "# Here we assign a value of 1 to a",
  "a" : 1,
  "b" : {
     "a" : 2,
     "c" : 3, "comment" : "# and c should be equal to 3",
     "d" : 4
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I wonder how to keep the ordering correct? When I rewrite using `canonical` format, all keys are sorted, it means comments will also be sorted, which is not desired..

Comment: JSON objects are explicitly unordered.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard task to maintain and modify configuration files and keep order including comments. See [Augeas](http://augeas.net) as an example of such system. It's not as easy as you expect according your example code. The Augeas, for example, uses a technique known as [lenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_transformation).

The main idea is to write new/own/special parser which stores additional information behind just semantic of content. It means the line numbers, the exact line position, comments, exact syntax variant used if there is such (For example escaping codes vs. characters, single vs. double quotes, used number base, format of float). And then use this information for serialization back. The lenses are just one quite elegant way how to write such parser. You write lens which is code working as parser and serializer at once.